# It doesn't work Consumer/Provider in the example - the tab hangs

Tags: reactjs

Why does the React tab in my browser hang when visualizing these components? What am I doing wrong? I just want to transfer the text to another component using Provider and Consumer.

Menu component:

```
import React, {PureComponent, createContext} from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './menu.scss';
import ShoppingBasket from '../shoppingBasket/shoppingBasket.js';

const UserContext = React.createContext({})
export const UserProvider = UserContext.Provider
export const UserConsumer = UserContext.Consumer

export default class Menu extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="head">
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/aboutus">About Us</Link>
        </nav>
        <UserProvider username={`name`}>
          <ShoppingBasket />
        </UserProvider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ShoppingBasket component:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'

import UserProvider from '../menu/menu.js';
import UserConsumer from '../menu/menu.js';

export default class ShoppingBasket extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserConsumer>
      {context => {
        return(
          <div>
            <h2>Profile Page of {context.username}</h2>
          </div>
        )
      }}
    </UserConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the React Context Api ,in Context Provider, data should be passed using the "value" prop , what you are doing it passing the username prop to the provider, what you should try is

```
<UserProvider value={`name`}>
    <ShoppingBasket />
 </UserProvider>
```

and while in the consumer

```
<UserConsumer>
      {value => {
        return(
          <div>
            <h2>Profile Page of {value}</h2>
          </div>
        )
      }}
</UserConsumer>
```

Comment: There's still a mistake ((

Comment: just tried on code sandbox , it works 
check out this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-hooks-sdyum?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It's just a page hangs. I have to kill it through my browser's Task Manager to restart. Error occurs only when I import and use component <UserConsumer>.

Comment: can you try importing in this way-
import { UserConsumer } from "path to the file" in ShoppingBasket component:

Comment: I got it! The error was that I exported the following: 
`import UserConsumer from '.../menu/menu.js'; `
and I should have exported it this way: 
`import { UserConsumer } from '.../menu/menu.js';`

What is the difference between these two methods of import?

Comment: what you were doing was using default  imports, in  a file ,  there can only be one default exports  ,which will used by Menu component, in order to use UserConsumer,UserProvider  will need to use named imports